# Newrez for KDE ? (resolution downsampling)

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card

I've found an interesting tool for using a higher screen resolution than my monitor can support, which is newrez.

Unfortunately, it's only for gnome desktop manager, is there any for KDE ?

Original post:

```
I'm trying to use the 1920x1200 resolution on my laptop that only support up to 1366x768.

The problem is I only found tutorials for nVidia GPUs, where my laptop only has an Intel HD Graphics 3000.

Moreover, is there any way to do it through a GUI even with a little modification in the X.Org files ?

My laptop is on Kubuntu 14.04.**2** 64bit

Ps: The goal is to have a decent workspace where I can align two A4 pages without scrolling, among other uses like coding etc
```

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, have you had any luck in the meantime?

Comment: Yup I did, it was just plain simple, see my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the Newrez author.

Being that this is just a script, there are lots of options.  One is just to execute it during login as a startup app.  As long as X is up, you are all set.  There is no dependency on Gnome or Nautilus.  It should run on anything.

Comment: Thank you for that very useful script ! By the way, is there any workarounds for the problems listed in my own answer (scale to ratio, dpi/blur, AMD/ATI/Nvidia working) just down here ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just plain simple, but it's not that perfect:

- First just download newrez's here (yes, you've heard it)

http://gtk-apps.org/content/show.php/newrez+-+Increase+Screen+Rez+For+Netbook?content=134686

- Then, put it somewhere and make it executable from GUI
- Just simply double-click on it and put your resolution

Now why it's not perfect:

- If you don't have a DPI scaler in your Desktop Environment, you'll go blind since views are so damn small
- I didn't find a way yet to prevent the stretching from 16/9 to 16/10
- The project's page mentions that it doesn't work for AMD/ATI and nVidia GPUs, but just give it a try. Maybe their own proprietary drivers can downsample too.
- When you want to come back to your default resolution, just put "default", since putting the pixels count in will make it back but it'll be blurry (dpi/"streching problems)

It's a script, so there must be a way to glue it into KDE, more infos here:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/increase-resolution-monitors-limit-newrez-linux/